# How can I change the size of a component based on the size of the previous one?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set the size of a component (the ResponsiveContainer) based on the size of the previous one (Typography). In fact in some cases the title I have in the Typography takes up too much space, so I would like to resize graphs. I can't find a solution...

```
return (
  <div id={containerName}>
    <Typography 
      className={classes.root} 
      align='justify' 
      variant='subtitle2'>
      {title}
    </Typography>
    <Box>
      <ResponsiveContainer
        width="98%"
        height={190}>
        <BarChart
          width={870}
          height={300}
          data={barData}
          onClick={onSelection}
          margin={{ top: 7, right: 1, bottom: 2, left: 5 }}>
          <Label value={xlabel} position="bottom"/>
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey={argumentField} />
          <YAxis />
          <Bar 
            dataKey={valueField} 
            fill={theme.palette.primary.main} 
            width={200} />
        </BarChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
    </Box>
  </div>)
);
```

I know that material-ui provides the useMediaQuery hook but how could I connect the two components?

Comment: Have a look at react references: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. I think they may be the way to go

Comment: Thank you, I solved!